# Xcode 10 Splash Screen Resizable Logo Image

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I'm currently working on an iOS application and I'm currently facing some problems with auto-layout.

My goal is the following:

- Centering the app logo horizontally and vertically (with upwards offset) in the center of the screen.
- Resizing (shrink / expand) the logo depending on iPhone device

I really don't know how I would rescale the image based on screen of the device. A mentor would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Center X and Y to center of the superview with your offset.

For the height and width you can add constraints with equal size to superview, and add multipliers to them.

**Tip:** If you want your `UIImageView` to be 40% of the width, you can set equal widths to superview with multiplier `0.4`. You can do the same for the height, or, you can set an aspect ratio to proportionally scale the height based on width or vice-versa.